# Mocking a visitor object using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I've written a piece of code that is responsible for creating an Issue.It uses a visitor pattern to set the Issue assignee.
Here's the code :

```
public Issue CreateIssue(IssueType type, string subject, string description, Priority priority, string ownerId)
        {
            var issue = new Issue
            {
                ...
            };
            IssueManagerContext.Current.IssueAssignmentMethodResolver(type).Visit(issue);
            ...
            return issue;
        }
```

I would like to test the functionality of this code thus somehow I need to mock the behavior of a visitor. After studying different Mock libraries I decided to use [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart).
But I don't know how should I build a mock object that gets an argument from my code instead of hard coding it as it's shown in the quick start guide.

Here's what I have done so far :

```
var visitor = new Mock<IIssueVisitor>();
visitor.Setup(x => x.Visit(null));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only match a specific instance of an object if the test has the same reference as the SUT. The problem in your scenario is that your SUT creates the instance `issue`, and returns it at the end of the method. Your test cannot access it *while the method is executing*, which precludes your mock object from being able to match it.

You can configure your mock object to match *any* `Issue` instance with the following syntax:

```
    visitor.Setup(x => x.Visit(It.IsAny<Issue>()));
```

You can also configure the mock to *conditionally* match an `Issue` instance:

```
    // Matches any instance of Issue that has an ID of 42
    visitor.Setup(x => x.Visit(It.Is<Issue>(theIssue => theIssue.ID == 42)));
```

If you want to match the reference of a *specific* instance of `Issue`, then you'll have to move the instantiation logic into some kind of abstraction (e.g., a factory) of which your test could provide a fake implementation. For example:

```
    // In SUT
    var issue = issueFactory.CreateIssue();
    ...

    // In test
    var stubIssue = new Issue{ ... };
    var issueFactory = new Mock<IIssueFactory>();
    var visitor = new Mock<IIssueVisitor>();
    ...        
    issueFactory.Setup(factory => factory.CreateIssue())
        .Returns(stubIssue);

    visitor.Setup(x => x.Visit(stubIssue));
```

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer :) the problem is my Create method is in fact a factory method itself. But It.IsAny<T> is suffice in my scenario.

Comment: Ahh. That *does* set things in a different perspective. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following syntax:

```
interface IFoo
{
    int Bar(string baz);
}

var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
mock.Setup(x => x.Bar(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns((string baz) => 42 /* Here baz contains the value your code provided */);
```